# Proving that if $a\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ then  $a=0$ or $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that if x is a vector and a is a scalar, then the following relation holds ?
1) if ax = 0, then either a = 0 or x = 0 ( or both).
This is trivial although i am unsure if my steps are correct.

step 1 
Lets pick $a = 0$ and $x  = (x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ where for all $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ are not zero.
$ax = ax_1 + ax_2 + \cdots + ax_n$ as multiplication by scalars is distributive.
Now can I just state $ax = ax_1 + ax_2 + \cdots + ax_n = 0$ as a is zero every where there doesn't seem to be any axiom of vector space which i could quote as reasoning there or is there ?

step 2
Lets pick $a\neq 0$ and $x  = (x_1, x2,\ldots, x_n)$ where for all $x_1,\ldots x_n$ are zero.
Again as before $ax = ax_1 + ax_2 + \cdots + ax_n$ as multiplication by scalars is distributive.

I know there is a zero vector in the vector space and according to my assumption $x$ is a zero vector but how do i justify $ax = 0$ ?

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You've (almost) said that $0 x = 0$ and that $a 0 = 0 $ for all $a$ and $x$. Note that this is *not* the same as showing that *if* $ax = 0$, *then* $a = 0 $ or $x = 0 $. You need to start with the statement "suppose $ax = 0 $", and then work from there.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that your vector space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual scalar multiplication? Note that $ax$ is **not** equal to $ax_1+ax_2+\cdots + ax_n$; rather, $$ax = a(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = (ax_1,\ldots,ax_n).$$

Comment: Hardy, when you make a question, deal longer to read the answers before making a new one. You made two question in the last 30 minutes.

Comment: @emiliocba : i do read the replies and ask questions under the same discussion , but i have a half dozen problems here out many more which i could not solve, i am not going to wait hours between each question. This is an open forum, i am not here to spam anyone i have a genuine question and i honestly value what people have to say as i am learning and clearing my doubts, so please just let me create and ask questions that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that your vectors are $n$-tuples of the form $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$.

As mentioned by Matt in his comment, you are not going about this in the right way.

The hypothesis is that $a\bf x=o$. So, 
what you need to assume is that $a\bf x=0$. 
Then you need to show that the result of the statement is true: you need to demonstrate that either $a=0$ or $\bf x=0$.

To do this: let's assume that $a\ne0$.  Now we need to demonstrate that $\bf x=0$.

By the definition of scalar multiplication:
$$
a{\bf x}=(ax_1, ax_2,\ldots,ax_n).
$$
But, as we asummed at the start, we  have $(ax_1, ax_2,\ldots,ax_n)=\bf0$. The only way this can happen is for each component to be zero. That is
$$
ax_1=0, ax_2=0,\ldots ax_n=0.
$$
Now, recalling that we have $a\ne0$, what can we say about each $x_i$? Then, what can we say about $\bf x$?

Comment: I guess we can say each of xi is the ith component of the zero vector, hence x must be the zero vector. Quick question why did u have to add the assumption "vectors are n-tuples of the form", are n't they always ?

Comment: @hardy I assumed they had $n$ components. You actually want to say "each $x_i$ is the scalar 0; so, $\bf x$ is the zero vector".

Comment: @ComicBookGuy - if by *vector* you mean an element of a vector space, then no, they are not always *n*-tuples. They may be any element from any set, along with operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ that satisfy the property of a vector space. eg the set of all lines with unit slope where vector addition is defined $(x + b_1) \oplus (x+b_2) = x+(b_1+b_2)$ and scalar multiplication is defined $k\odot (x+b_1) = x + kb_1$ is a vector space, and the elements ("vectors") have the form $y_1 = x + b_1$, $y_2 = x + b_2$ etc.

Answer (score 5):

Your operations are incorrect, even assuming that you are allowed to assume that a vector is a "tuple". Note that for $\alpha$ a scalar and $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, the usual scalar multiplication is defined to be
$$\alpha\mathbf{x} = \alpha(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = (\alpha x_1,\ldots,\alpha x_n).$$
You have $\alpha x_1+\cdots \alpha x_n$, which would make it a *scalar*, not a vector. And distributivity of scalar multiplication has nothing to do with it.

Also: even if correct, your argument would only have established that (i) if $a=0$ and $\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}$, then $a\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$; and (ii) if $a\neq 0$ and $\mathbf{x}= \mathbf{0}$ then $a\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. But this is *not* what you need to prove! What you need to prove is the implication going *the other way*: **if** $a\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, then $a=0$ or $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ (or both).

To that end, you would begin with: "assume that $a$ is a scalar, and $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector, **and** $a\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$..."

**Hint.** If $a=0$, then we are done. The only other alternative is that $a\neq 0$. If $a\neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{a}$ makes sense, and is a scalar. Now use two of the properties of scalar multiplication to show that if $a\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ but $a\neq 0$, then $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i appreciate your help, i guess i did n't even understand the question correctly. I will attempt a proof based on your hint and write back here.

Comment: I am unsure how i could use the scalar 1/a ?

Comment: Not much you can do with a scalar and a vector, except multiply them. What happens if you multiply $\frac{1}{a}$ by $a\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: we get x right as 1/a cancels with a as the multiplication with a scalar is associative, what would we do next ?

Comment: @Hardy: That's just *one* side of the equation $a\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, though.

Comment: i guess we end up with 1x  = 0 which by B(2) ( multiplication identity) property of vec spaces we get 1x = x = 0 hence x must be 0 vector for our original ax = 0 assumption to hold. was that correct ?

Comment: @Hardy: Yes; that's the end of the argument.