# Does $\lambda$ $\mathbf u$ $= 0$ imply $\lambda = 0$ or $\mathbf u$ $= 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Does $\lambda \mathbf u = 0$  imply $\lambda = 0 $ or $\mathbf u= 0$
where $\mathbf u$ is in a vector space $V$ over a field $F$.

The case for the vector equalling zero is trivial due to the fact field axioms include a multiplicative inverse, so how could I show lambda is 0?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: Consider the components of the vector after they've been multiplied by $\lambda$. Since they each must be 0, your conclusion is straightforward.

Comment: And to be more specific, it is an "or" not an "and"

Comment: Yes the u= 0 is quite trivial, but what about the lambda=0? Can you use the vector spacw and field axioms to show this?

Comment: I have edited my question to emphasise for lambda

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103428/proving-that-if-a-mathbfx-mathbf0-then-a-0-or-mathbfx-mathbf0/201168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the other answers is clear that if $\mathbf v=\mathbf 0_V$ then $\lambda\mathbf v=\mathbf 0_V$ for any $\lambda\in\Bbb F$. Then I will show the other cases.

---

First I will show that $0_{\Bbb F}\mathbf v=\mathbf 0_V$ for any $\mathbf v\in V$. Suppose that $\mathbf v\neq \mathbf 0_V$, then by the properties of the field $\Bbb F$ and some axioms of a vector space we have that

$$0_{\Bbb F}\mathbf v=(0_{\Bbb F}+0_{\Bbb F})\mathbf v=0_{\Bbb F}\mathbf v+0_{\Bbb F}\mathbf v\tag{1}$$

And

$$0_{\Bbb F}\mathbf v+0_{\Bbb F}(-\mathbf v)=\mathbf 0_V\tag{2}$$

Then adding in both sides of $(1)$ the vector $0_{\Bbb F}(-\mathbf v)$ we can conclude that $0_{\Bbb F}\mathbf v=\mathbf 0_V$.

---

It remains to show that if $\lambda\neq 0_{\Bbb F}$ and $\mathbf v\neq \mathbf 0_V$ then $\lambda\mathbf v\neq\mathbf 0_V$.

Suppose to the contrary that $\lambda\neq0_{\Bbb F}$, $\mathbf v\neq \mathbf 0_V$ but $\lambda\mathbf v=\mathbf 0_V$. Then from the axioms of a vector space we knows that $\mathbf v=1_{\Bbb F}\cdot\mathbf v$, hence

$$(\lambda+1_{\Bbb F})\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v+\mathbf v=\mathbf v\tag{3}$$

Now adding in both sides of $(3)$ the vector $(\lambda+1_{\Bbb F})(-\mathbf v)$ we get

$$(\lambda+1_{\Bbb F})\mathbf 0_V=\lambda(-\mathbf v)\tag{4}$$

and because $\lambda\neq 0_{\Bbb F}$ (and $\lambda\mathbf 0_V=\mathbf 0_V$ as other answers shown) then multiplying both sides of $(4)$ by $1/\lambda$ we get

$$\frac{\lambda+1_{\Bbb F}}{\lambda}\mathbf 0_V=\mathbf 0_V=(-\mathbf v)\implies\mathbf v=\mathbf 0_V\tag{5}$$

but we says that $\mathbf v\neq \mathbf 0_V$, so we get a contradiction. Hence if $\lambda\neq 0_{\Bbb F}$ and $\mathbf v\neq \mathbf 0_V$ then it cannot be possible that $\lambda\mathbf v= \mathbf 0_V$.$\square$

Comment: But you have assume lambda is 0 from the beginning of your argument? My main confusion is you assumed lambda is 0 and proceeded to show we in fact get the 0 vector. So we know if lambda IS 0, then we get the zero vector, but can we show that if u is not 0 then lambda must be equal to zero? What if lambda is not zero and we still get zero? Or am I missing something crucial in your answer? Is it because of the uniqueness of the zero element?

Comment: @14tim4 you are not missing something... it was too late when I wrote this answer. Indeed we need to show that if $\lambda\neq 0_{\Bbb F}$ and $\mathbf v\neq \mathbf 0_V$ then $\lambda\mathbf v\neq\mathbf 0_V$.

Comment: This is a wonderful conclusion!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, for suppose $\lambda \neq 0$. Then
$$\lambda u = 0$$ 
$$\implies u=\frac{1}{\lambda}\lambda u = \frac{1}{\lambda }0 = 0$$

Comment: Yes this part I have no problem with, it's trivial it's the lambda part due to the fact that the field axioms include a multiplicative inverse, and the vector space axioms do not.

Comment: $\lambda$ is an element of a field, and it's not zero, so it has a multiplicative inverse. Further, it's a vector space axiom that for any scalars $a,b$ and any vector $v$ we have $a(bv) = (ab)v$.

Answer (score 2):

This is true as it is actually a theorem about general vector spaces. The proof for this is pretty straightforward as well, by showing that if $\lambda u = \vec{0} $ and $\lambda \ne 0$ then a logical consequence is that $u$ must be the zero vector. And of course, if $\lambda = 0$, it is another known theorem that for all $u$ in a given vector space that $0u = \vec{0}$ ($\vec{0}$ being the zero vector).

Comment: Can you be more specific with the lambda part? Using the axioms

Comment: If you are asking that when we assume $\lambda = 0$ and proving that $u$ is the zero vector, I would look at the answer provided by Macacroso.

Comment: His step (2) is the Additive Inverse axiom of Vector Spaces and (1) is first using a property of zero, then using the Second Distributive axiom of Vector Spaces

Answer (score 1):

I know I already answered but to help you with your confusion I am going to throw in another one.

Let's assume we have a vector space $\mathbf{V}$ and for $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbf{V}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ we know that  $\lambda \mathbf u = \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf u \ne \mathbf{0}.$ The next part of the proof could vary as it depends on how the scalar multiplication is defined for $\mathbf{V}$ but for simplicity reasons I am going to let $\mathbf{V} = \mathbb{R}^n$ and show that it works in this case. You can feel free to check for other vector spaces.

Anyway, now we have that $\lambda \mathbf{u} =\lambda \left(u_1, u_2, \dots u_n \right) =\left(\lambda u_1,\lambda u_2, \dots \lambda u_n \right) $ where $u_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all integers $1 \le i \le n$ and $\exists{u_i}$ such that $u_i \ne 0$. Substituting back in we get $\left(\lambda u_1,\lambda u_2, \dots \lambda u_n \right) = \mathbf{0}$.

Now we have a system of linear equations to solve for. $$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
u_1 \lambda = 0 \\ 
u_2 \lambda = 0 \\ 
\vdots \\
u_n \lambda = 0
\end{array}
\right.$$

We know that $\lambda = 0$ is a solution just from observation. And because of the fact that there is at least one $u_i$ that is not $0$ then it turns out that $\lambda = 0$ is the only solution.

I hope this helps on your confusion.

Comment: This makes sense! Showing for other vectors spaces should not be too much, if I'm correct we can define linear transformations from a any vector space to a coordinate vector in field $$F^n$$ anyway (I think). Your answer also relies on the fact that two scalars equaling zero, one of them must be equal to zero, which is quite easy to prove. Such a simple and beautiful proof. I wish I could select  multiple correct answers. Thank you